# Wordpress theme with multiple color schemes

Tags: themes, theme-development

I am building a WP theme and want to implement multiple color schemes. I looked through different free and premium themes and found out that this feature is developed different ways there and here. What is the best practice to make multiple color schemes support in a theme?

Comment: First we need to know how you plan to use multiple color schemes.  Do you want each page to have a different color?  Do you want each post to have a different color?  Do you want to change color based on the current user?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer? [Theme options page](http://wpshout.com/create-an-advanced-options-page-in-wordpress/) + secondary, conditionally-loaded CSS files = Joy in Mudville.